# Getting C++ Pointer to pointer reference back from function

Tags: c++, vb.net, pointers

Currently i'm stuck on a function call from a C++ unmaged DLL.

It has a function to get values. However the return value of the function is a boolean (true if no error). The value we want is in one of the parameters: `const char** value` If i understand C++ correctly this is a pointer to a pointer. Normally a pointer can be handled in .net by using ByRef at the parameter, changing the value you put in to. However i don't how to get an pointer to pointer working.

Short story: 
How to convert:

```
extern "C" __EXPORT bool funcName(const char** value)
```

To C# / VB.net

This works for `const char* value` but not for `const char** value`

```vb
<DllImport("Path_To_Dll.Dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Shared Function FuncName(ByRef GetValue as string) as boolean
End Function

Dim HereReturnValue as string

Private Function GetValue() as string
    FuncName(HereReturnValue)
    Return HereReturnValue
End Function
```

Comment: `ByRef IntPtr`, then you need unsafe code to make a `Byte*` that can be passed to the `System::String` constructor.  Don't forget to pass the pointer back to the right deallocation function provided by the library, whatever that is.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for giving this golden advice. In order to work with a unmanaged value you have to store it in memory and then make a copy of it which we can work with. More info can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Marshal.Copy` is really not what you want here.  If it were a user-defined type, then `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` would be appropriate; since it is a string then [`Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe(v=vs.110).aspx) is the right tool for making a copy into a managed object.